# Transmit an Eddystone Beacon with name using Altbeacon Library

Tags: android, altbeacon, eddystone

I use the following code transmiting as Eddystone using my Android device;

```
 try {
            byte[] urlBytes = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.compress("http://www.****.com");
            Identifier encodedUrlIdentifier = Identifier.fromBytes(urlBytes, 0, urlBytes.length, false);
            ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<Identifier>();
            identifiers.add(encodedUrlIdentifier);
            Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                    .setBluetoothName("devicename")
                    .setIdentifiers(identifiers)
                    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                    .setTxPower(-59)
                    .build();
            BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT);
            BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
            beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("ww", "That URL cannot be parsed");
        }
```

I can not get beacon.getBluetoothName() when scan device. Is it possible to add name. I added using .setBluetoothName("devicename") but it is not showing when scan. It return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not possible to add a Bluetooth name to a beacon advertisement, as there is simply not enough room in the limited data packet size of a BLE advertisement.

The field on the `Beacon` has no effect on transmissions.  It is only populated when scanning for beacons.  When scanning, the data comes from a separate packet called the scan response.  For practical purposes it is read only.

It is possible to change a phone's BLE name that appears in the phone's own scan response.  However, changing this name affects not just beacon transmissions but all Bluetooth operations on the phone. This is yet another reason that the library's BeaconTransmitter does not change this name. You can do so youself, however, by calling the setName method on Android's `BluetoothAdapter` class.

Comment: So what should I do to distinguish it from other beacons when scanning for beacon? Because when also scan in IOS, bluetooth address and bluetooth name return nil.

Comment: The Eddystone url formal is not designed to be distinguishable from other beacon transmission by any mechanism other than the uniqueness of the url itself.  If you have room in the URL you could add a unique path or query sting at the end.    You can also distinguish using the Mac address on Android or the peripheral identifier field in iOS.  These rotate periodically but stay the same for ~15 minutes

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to get Eddystone beacon url in swift. I cant see after scanning in beacon object.

Comment: The Swift issue is worthy of a new question as there is no room to answer in comments.  Are you already using detection code?  This code has a similar url beacon compressor class: https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools